# Net Core: Use Command Line to Change 'Default Project' in 'Package Manager Console' Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

How do I change the Default Project through Package Manager Console? What is the command line in PM> instead of moving mouse dropdown, and selecting item?
Is there command line?

[image]

Context: We eventually want to run Powershell scripts, to rescaffold all our 5 databases to the project folders in Entity Framework.

Comment: Well, if your goal is to automate through scripting, you might be better off just using the `-ProjectName` switch for the cmdlets or using nuget.exe itself.

Comment: well I know to change directory in command prompts, it cd TestDirectory etc, what is change project name in Nuget?

Comment: In the console, if you wanted to target a project named `TestProject`, you would install a package like `Install-Package My.Package.Name -ProjectName TestProject`

Comment: @JonathonChase I need to scaffold a database, and need to change the project name it goes to

Comment: Like what Jonathon suggested, specify the Project name when using nuget commands. To rescaffold database to project folder, it seems not something about nuget. You can do it even in cmd.exe .

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the very same result by using the `-Project` parameter of the migration commands in Package Manager Console.

[Entity Framework Core tools reference - Package Manager Console in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#common-parameters)

Both `add-migration` and `update-database` commands have the common parameters: `-Project` and `-StartupProject`, so you can write a complete migration command/script what are unaware what are the dropdown settings in the PM window.

Answer (score 1):

I found this when searching for a similar requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#target-and-startup-project

```
Scaffold-DbContext -StartupProject {an appropriate project} -Project ...
```

My particular case is the first typical scenario listed in the Microsoft documentation.

- "The EF Core context and entity classes are in a .NET Core class library."

I have a small project that is used only for EF Scaffolding and that project name is what I pass to the `-StartupProject` argument. I was tired of changing the Default project dropdown when working on a large solution with many projects, the majority of which did not reference the EntityFrameworkCore package (nor should they).